# PHP Concurrent HTTP requests?

Tags: php, http, concurrency, request

I was wondering what the best way to do concurrent HTTP requests in PHP? I have a lot of data to get and i'd rather do multiple requests at once to retrieve it all.

Does anybody know how I can do this? Preferably in an anonymous/callback function mannor...

Thanks,

Tom.

Comment: Like [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) the [`http`](http://php.net/http) extension also provides for concurrent requests, using the [`HttpRequestPool`](http://php.net/HttpRequestPool) class (which in turn just uses curl behind the scenes).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240267/asynchronous-http-requests-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallel HTTP requests in PHP using PECL HTTP classes \[Answer: HttpRequestPool class\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168951/parallel-http-requests-in-php-using-pecl-http-classes-answer-httprequestpool-cl)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [curl_multi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php), which internally fires off multiple separate requests under a single curl handle.

But otherwise PHP itself not in any way/shape/form "multithreaded" and will not allow things to run in parallel, except via gross hacks (multiple parallel scripts, one script firing up multiple background tasks via exec(), etc...).

Comment: Things are changed, now PHP can make async calls using the Fibers which is included in PHP 8.1

Answer (score 2):

You can try either [curl_multi()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi.php) or use a lower level function [socket_select()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use HttpRequestPool [http://www.php.net/manual/de/httprequestpool.construct.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequestpool.construct.php)

```
$multiRequests = array(
  new HttpRequest('http://www.google.com', HttpRequest::METH_GET),
  new HttpRequest('http://www.yahoo.com', HttpRequest::METH_GET)
  new HttpRequest('http://www.bing.com', HttpRequest::METH_GET)
);

$pool = new HttpRequestPool();
foreach ($multiRequests as $request)
{
  $pool->attach($request);
}

$pool->send();

foreach($pool as $request) 
{
  echo $request->getResponseBody();
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error while testing this code : Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found.

Comment: You are probably using version 2 of pecl_http. In case you want to use HttpRequest you need to install pecl_http 1.7.6, I think. Version 2 has been completly rewritten years ago, nevertheless the documentation on php.net refers to version 1

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want you can send you data as json. In php you can defragment it into all the values again. for eg.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "gotoChatRoomorNot.php?q=[{"+str+"},{"+user1+"},{"+user2"}]", true);
```

and in php you can follow this to get your data back: [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

So make a string in json format and send the entire thing through http.
I think you can perform the same kind of behaviour with xml, but i am not aware of xml