# Fastest way to get multiple pages from a single domain?

Tags: php, http

Let's say I need to get content from 5 different websites, 100 pages from each. For instance:

```
example.com/?a=1, 
example.com.com/?a=2 
OR 
example.com/a.txt, 
example.com/b.txt
```

Up until now, I have been using `curl_multi`, and while this is much faster than normal curl, I'm still not completely satisfied with the speed. I was wondering if there was a faster way to get pages from a single domain (connect to the domain, then grab as much as you can!).

I do not own the domain I am trying to get content from, but I will be throttling my requests.

Comment: Why the downvote and close? What needs to be fixed?

Comment: This isn't a programming question at all. Just a guess.

Comment: Why isn't it a programming question? He's asking for a more efficient method of what he is currently doing with `curl_multi`

Comment: I'm not looking for code, I'm really just wondering if using an fsock stream is faster. I don't want to spend the time reorganizing a huge application if it's not better.

Comment: Use [HTTP/1.1's Pipelining](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the server implementation. Regarding resources it's a good idea to use one TCP connection by using one [HTTP/1.1's persistent connection](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html). But it's very likely that the server implementation will handle those requests sequentially, as HTTP wants them delivered in the same order.

So if those requests needs some server side processing time you probably go faster by parallel requests. If not I guess the overhead of several connections will be out performed by one connection. At the end you'll have to benchmark the different approaches for your resources.

I guess a mix of both methods will lead to the most time efficient result, as there are resources which are delivered instantly, and some which have some processing latency.

Comment: I see, do you know if fsock / streams have anything to do with this kind of persistent connection? "Steam" sounds like something that has to do with it, though I'm still reading the manual and pipelining.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168951/parallel-http-requests-in-php-using-pecl-http-classes-answer-httprequestpool-c